# How to correctly use the agent selector (@c)?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I'm new to Minecraft commands, so this may be a very dumb question.

I was playing with the NPC dialog, adding some random commands to understand how they work.
I first tried to give something to myself, and it worked as expected:

```
/give @s camera 1
```

Then I tried to give something to the agent:

```
/give @c carrot 5
```

but I got an error:

> Selector must be player-type.

What I understand is that the agent is considered an entity. So far, so good.
So... what exactly can I do with the agent selector `@c` then? Am I able to interact with my agent using commands?

PS:
Apart from `/kill` and `/teleport`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/give` is not compatible with the Agent, however, `/replaceitem` is. Use `/replaceitem` instead to add items to your Agent's inventory with commands:

```
replaceitem entity @c slot.inventory 0 carrot 5
```

Comment: I knew it would be you the one to answer, thank you!